# Android, make portions of text invisible in TextView

Tags: android, text, visibility

I suspect that adding a certain letter/character to the beginning of my text will solve an alignment problem I am currently facing. Needless to say that I do not wish for this letter to appear.
Is there a way to tell a portion of the text to be invisible/transparent?
I reviewed the *Spannable*  interface could not find anything related to visibility.

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: I presume a space wont suffice? I dont think theres a way to make part of a TextViews contents invisible. TransformationMethod is used to display text is a password form (Ex: "....") so you could look into that? It make allow you to set some text invisible with a different transforamtion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suspect that adding a certain
>   letter/character to the beginning of
>   my text will solve an alignment
>   problem I am currently facing.

It is unrealistic for this technique to work for all screen sizes, all screen densities, and all font sizes.

> Is there a way to tell a portion of
>   the text to be invisible/transparent?

You can tell a portion of the text to have the same color as the background, assuming you know what your background color is.

Comment: Thanks! I eventually figured this out myself... cilly me... but it doesn't seem to work. I followed the official Dev guide and implied, for example:   
str.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFFFFF00), 8, 19, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

Strange...

Comment: You're changing the background color in that code. If you want the text to be invisible, change the text color.

Comment: Right... thanks. I used BackgroundColorSpan instead of ForegroundColorSpan... much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

You can set invividual colors in a TextView, try looking at this example of multiple colours used in text [from anddev](http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=22469). The colour codes are given as ARGB, so you can define the alpha; you would simple use alpha = 0 to make completely transparent. I.E. #00FF0000 would give invisible red text.

I assume you have already tried using android:paddingLeft="1dip" or similar?